# ¿como hacer una llamada con un numero o un nombre predeterminado?

Tags: java, android

Deseo hacer una llamada y que a la persona que lo recibe aparece otro número a la actual, ahora sólo que realizo la llamada, necesito pasar como parámetro un nombre o número para que le aparezca a la persona que recibe la llamada, actualmente este es el código

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1645"));
intent.setAction(intent.ACTION_CALL);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Lo siento Heyner pero esto no puede ser posible en Android, modificar el nombre o numero a la persona que reciba la llamada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de tanto tiempo agrego la solución a la pregunta.
 Intent intent = new Intent();

```
intent.setAction(intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:600"));
        intent.putExtra("account", 0);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Cabe anotar que el dispositivo manejó varias cuentas de teléfono y por lo tanto el código no trabajó

Answer (score 1):

Por medio de este Intent, únicamente puedes marcar al número que especificas. Lo que deseas:

> necesito pasar como parámetro un nombre o número para que le aparezca
>   a la persona que recibe la llamada

**por medio de [ACTION_CALL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) u otro método NO se pueden modificar los datos que recibe la persona a recibir la llamada.**